# Join query in DataStore JPA java- App engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, jpa

I want to fetch data from two different entites in JPA. I am using Google DataStore with App Engine to store my data on cloud storage. Now what i want is to fetch data from two different entites by making use of `Join` query.As i am new to app engine and datastore, i don't know how to do that. I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029539/jpa-criteria-with-datastore-in-google-app-engine) link and it says that DataStore doesn't support joins properly. Is that true? Pleas eguide me to solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The are ample places where it is stated clearly that GAE/Datastore does not do "join queries". Such as https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/overview-dn2

If instead you are using google-cloud-sql (why you tag this question as SQL?) then I suggest you update your question to state that

Comment: ok..so how i'll achieve this functionality ? Is there any other way?

Comment: You mean apart from the answer in the linked question saying that classes can be embedded if needing to do that?

Comment: Is there any other way to fetch data from multiple entities in DataStore?

Comment: I am using JPA not JDO. So is it possible make joins in JPA with Datastore app engine ?

Comment: The API has ZERO to do with it. The Datastore has everything to do with it. Those statements are explicit.

Answer (score 1):

How to join records when your data store does not: write a join in the client application code.  Warning - depending on the data, doing this might cost a lot of overhead.  This is a straw man answer designed to justify the real answer in the final paragraph.

Conceptually, your application could implement a nested loop join as follows.  Choose the entity whose expected record count is lowest for the outer loop.  Create a query to iterate over those records.  Within the iterator loop for each record, copy the fields used for joining into variables, then create an inner nested query that takes these variables as parameters.  Iterate over the records produced by the inner query, and for each inner record, produce a record of output using data from both the inner and the outer current entities.

Because an external nested loop join is such a bad idea, you should really consider redesigning your current schema to produce the results you are after without requiring a join at all.  Start by just imagining the output that you want coming directly out of entities of just one Kind.  That usually means letting go of relational normal forms.  After you have designed appropriate NoSQL structures that can deliver the required outputs, you should then design appropriate NoSQL algorithms to write the data that way.